# Installing NLTK in Python 2.7 when it already exists in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to install NLTK package in Python 2.7 - I already have it installed in Python 3. So every time I run :

`sudo pip install nltk`

I get:

> Requirement already satisfied: nltk in
>   /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied: six in
>   /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nltk)

How do i specifically install `nltk` in python 2.7 instead?

Thanks a lot!

Jay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way for install the `nltk` module with Python 2.7 version is this one:

```
sudo pip2 install nltk
```

It will automatically recognize your Python 2.7 version. But you can also be more specific if you have more than one version for Python 2. In that case you could change `pip2` to `pip2.7`. In general the PIP command from version 1.5 supports the `pipVERSION` argument (see below some examples for different versions of Python environment):

```
$ pip2.6 install SomePackage # Python 2.6
$ pip2.7 install SomePackage # Python 2.7
$ pip3.6 install SomePackage # Python 3.6
```

#### How to solve the `sudo:pip2 command not found`

**(IMPORTANT: be sure of have the correct version of Python 2.7 installed. If you are not sure, please just download it from : https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/. For example if you are on Mac machine you need for sure to download it again cause the default version already installed doesn't work properly sometimes with NLTK module).**

As the user @kittcar encountered this kind of error I'll show a couple of solutions for find a way around the problem:

- The first option is to type on command line: `easy_install pip`
  This will automatically install all the dependencies for your current Python versions. (See the picture below)

[image: execution of easy_install pip command]

**IMPORTANT:** If you don't have the `easy_install` command just run:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python`

- The second option (if for some reasons the first option doesn't work) is to type:

`curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and 
`python27 get-pip.py`

Basically you take the source from the target url and then you install PIP for Python 2.7 version.

- The third option is to use the `conda` instead of `pip` command if you use (like in my personal case) the **Anaconda Environment** and you want to install the `nltk` module fastly. In that case you just need to follow these steps:

  1. Download the zip source: https://gist.github.com/danielfrg/d17ffffe0dc8ed56712a0470169ff546.
  2. Extract the folder and rename as **"nltk-with-data"**.
  3. Change directory to one directory above the nltk-with-data directory with `cd` command.
  4. Run conda build for different Python versions that you need, selecting the packages for the platform and OS you are running the command on.

Below the command list:

```
conda build nltk-with-data --python 2.7 # you need this one! :-)
conda build nltk-with-data --python 3.4
conda build nltk-with-data --python 3.5
conda build nltk-with-data --python 3.6
```

Finally you just need to run `conda install nltk-with-data` and `ipython` for conclude the nltk installation. And then you just need to type:

```
import nltk.corpus
nltk.corpus.treebank
```

As you can see from my screenshot everything went fine and I have successfully installed the `nltk` module for Python 2.7 with the Anaconda Environment:

[image: nltk-conda-install]

Feel free to ask me everything, in particular let me know if you successfully fixed your problem or not. If not, please update your question with command line error logs and your current machine details. So I can understand better what exactly causes your problem and I can suggest you the worth solution for solve it.

Comment: Yah I tried : sudo pip2 install nltk , it says : sudo:pip2 command not found

Comment: Probably you didn't install `PIP` for Python 2.7 but only `PIP3` (it's just for Python 3 version). Try `easy_install pip`

Comment: @UgoL yes. Actually this is a possibility. For completeness try to see also the PIP version installed by typing one of the following: `pip -V` or `pip --version` or `pip list`

Comment: yah it only shows it installed on python 3.6 pip 9.0.1 from /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6) ........Any idea how to install it in python 2.7.....easy_install pip didn't do it

Comment: @kyttcar be sure to have Python 2.7 correctly installed (**be sure of this point**). If you have it, try `pip install --upgrade pip`. If it doesn't work you need to try this: `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
`python27 get-pip.py` Basically you are trying to install the specific PIP version for Python 2.7 from a specific url.

Comment: Yah, Here is the path for 2.7 : /anaconda/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7........Is it maybe because I am in the wrong $PATH

Comment: Well... you are running Anaconda environment (probably Jupyter notebook too..)... hmm I think that if this environment works with Python 2.7 as default you could try to install the nltk module with `conda install -c anaconda nltk`

Comment: I tried : conda install -c anaconda nltk . It updates python 3.6 only and doesn't seem to pick up python 2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162200/discussion-between-giulio-bambini-and-kyttcar).

Comment: @GiulioBambini My fix was as simple as re-downloading python 2.7 - Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: @kyttcar nice! I’m happy that you solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the solutions given in the 2 answers posted above did not work for me. Both `pip` and `pip2` were installing the same new version of `nltk` that was not compatible with python2.7. Thankfully, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869915) of another question, [Install older (but stable) NLTK version compatible with python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866947/install-older-but-stable-nltk-version-compatible-with-python-2), solved the problem. The solution is to specify explicitly the version of `nltk` to be installed when using the `pip` command:

```
pip install nltk==3.4.5
```

Versions of `nltk` higher than 3.4.5 happen to be incompatible with Python 2

Answer (score 2):

you should use different pip for python 2 and 3. Or just virtual env.
Anyway, another possible idea to Giulio Bambini's response is:

```
python2.7 -m pip install <module>
```

with

> sudo

if necessary