# Install older (but stable) NLTK version compatible with python 2

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, python-2.x

I would like to install an older (but stable) version of NLTK for python2.7.
I tried to run the command: `pip install nltk===x.x.x` but the terminal reports many errors.
I was wondering if there's a repository where nltk can be downloaded or whether there are some other ways to solve the problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://www.nltk.org/news.html , `v3.4.5` should be the last version for Python 2 support.

```
pip install nltk==3.4.5
```

Note: However, it is strongly recommended to use NLTK with Python 3.